# How to Write an Equality Method in Java

Tags: java, equality

Consider adding an equality method to the following class of simple points:

```
public class Point {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    // ...
}
```

// my definition of equals

```
public boolean equals(Point other) {
  return (this.getX() == other.getX() && this.getY() == other.getY());
}
```

What's wrong with this method? At first glance, it seems to work OK:

```
Point p1 = new Point(1, 2);
Point p2 = new Point(1, 2);

Point q = new Point(2, 3);

System.out.println(p1.equals(p2)); // prints true

System.out.println(p1.equals(q)); // prints false
```

However, trouble starts once you start putting points into a collection:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

HashSet<Point> coll = new HashSet<Point>();
coll.add(p1);

System.out.println(coll.contains(p2)); // prints false
```

How can it be that coll does not contain p2, even though p1 was added to it, and p1 and p2 are equal objects?

Comment: Good explanation here:
http://bytes.com/topic/java/insights/723476-overriding-equals-hashcode-methods Internalize this - it is one of the most fundamental rules in Java and a frequent interview question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it is true that you should implement `hashCode()` when you implement `equals()`, that is not causing your problem.

That is not the `equals()` method you are looking for.  The equals method must always have the following signature: "public boolean equals(Object object)".  Here is some code.

```
public boolean equals(Object object)
{
  if (object == null)
  {
    return false;
  }

  if (this == object)
  {
    return true;
  }

  if (object instanceof Point)
  {
    Point point = (Point)object;
    ... now do the comparison.
  }
  else
  {
     return false;
  }
}
```

The [Apache EqualsBuilder class](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) is useful for equals implementations.  The link is an older version, but still applicable.

If you liked the Apache EqualsBuilder, you will probably like the [Apache HashCodeBuilder class](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) as well.

**Edit:** updated the equals method example for standard shortcuts.

Comment: @Louis: Almost the only one... :-)

Comment: Well.  The only one as of my comment that I saw.

Comment: This is correct, but the cause of the problem above is still `hashCode()` not being implemented. `HashSet` (et al.) uses `hashCode()` to determine which bucket an element belongs to, so the signature of `equals()` wouldn't make a difference in the behaviour of the above code example. It would make a difference (and cause other kinds of mysterious behaviour) only after `hashCode` is correctly implemented.

Answer (score 4):

You must implement `hashCode()` whenever you override `equals()`. These two work together, and they must give consistent results at all times. Failing to do so produces just the erroneous behaviour you observed.

This is explained in more detail e.g. in [*Effective Java 2nd Edition*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), Item 9: **Always override hashCode when you override equals**.

Answer (score 2):

Works well by overriding hashcode !

Always remember : **override hashCode when you override equals.**

```
@Override public int hashCode() {
        return (41 * (41 + getX()) + getY());
    }
```

This is my implementations of hashCode.

Comment: This doesn't generate a unique hash... 2 simple examples `x=1`, `y=0`, `Hash=1722` OR `x=0`, `y=41`, `Hash=1722`

Answer (score 1):

As per contract on `equals()` you need to implement `hashCode()` as well.

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) on `equals()`:

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers:

If you are using Eclipse as IDE, you can simply use "Source" --> "Generate hashCode() and equals() to get a basic implementation. Do with that what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

When overriding `equals`, you also have to override `hashCode` (in particular, if you are going to use `HashSet` or `HashMap`...). A suitable (though not to clever) implementation would be:

```
int hashCode() {
    return x * 31 + y;
}
```

Another point (no pun intended): You are not actually overriding the `equals(Object)` method defined in class `Object`, but instead are defining a new one. The correct way would be:

```
boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == this) return true;
    else if (!(other instanceof Point)) return false;
    else {
        Point p = (Point)other;
        return x == p.getX() && y == p.getY();
    }
}
```

Note, that the `equals` method has a [pretty strong contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) associated with it, which you are to fulfill.